# What is this insect flying in my Los Angeles bathroom?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

We live in the Los Angeles area. This insect has been very common in our bathrooms recently:
[image: mothlike-insect]

They're about 1/4" long, and can often be found resting on our towels. In the months leading up to December, we've been seeing them more and more.

- Do they cause any harm?
- Could they be responsible for the holes I've
  been finding in my shirts?
- Even if they're just a nuisance, how can
  we get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the common clothes moth (*Tineola bisselliella*). And, yes, the larvae (caterpillars) are likely the source of the holes in your shirts. You can purchase traps online or from hardware stores, or you can go the pesticide route if necessary (e.g., Delta Dust is available from online retailers).
See this site for further info, or search the web for more info on this species. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tineola_bisselliella

Comment: I thought about moths, but I read that the larva only attack clothes in airtight storage. My shirts are in a closet where I rarely close the door, and I wear them frequently. Was I wrong?